# SUMA DE NÚMEROS CON UN CRITERIO

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en la cual registro algunos eventos, dentro de esa tabla tengo 2 columnas: MONTO y ESTATUS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, lo que quiero es mostrarle al usuario final la suma de cada uno de esos eventos, es decir, FRUSTRADOS = $3,000   CONCRETADOS = $5,000. Actualmente estoy usando este código:

```
        <?php
        $query="SELECT SUM(monto) as `total` FROM farderos WHERE estatus = 0";
        $res=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
        $data=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        ?>
        <b>Recuperado: <?php echo "<b> $ </b>".$data['total']; ?> </b>
```

En la parte del: estatus = 1 o 0, es porque al momento de capturar el registro el usuario debe de poner 1 una vez que el evento se ha concretado y 0 cuando fue frustrado. Pero no me esta respetando el criterio.

En espera de su ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: Por favor pon la estructura de la tabla pero en lenguaje SQL para poder ayudarte

Comment: El código está correcto y efectivamente muestra la suma de uno de los estatus.
Para hacer la suma de ambos estatus, la forma más fácil es hacer la consulta dos (2) veces. Una para cada estatus (estatus=0 y estatus=1). Para no escribir código de más, puedes usar una función y solo mandarle el parámetro 0 o 1 y que devuelva el valor de la suma según ese criterio.

Comment: Con `php` haz dos consultas, una para los concretados y una para los frustrados

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿desde la base de datos vienen las cantidades con el signo de $?

Comment: @FernandoUrban no, el signo de pesos no esta en base de datos, muchas gracias por su apoyo, ya resolví el problema, sólo eran errores al ingresar los registros.